# why data not pass correctly codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter framework. In that model file i want to get count of answer , not answer.etc. my model like this.

```
     function daily_report() {
     $user = $this->session->userdata['id'];
      $date = $this->input->post('sdate');

      $sql="SELECT count(cl.`C_ansornot`) as bb, u.`E_name` 
          FROM `call` as cl
            inner join `user` as u on u.`idEmployee` = cl.`idEmployee`";


     $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach ($query as $row){
       //  var_dump($query) ;
      $sql1="SELECT
               count(`C_ansornot`) answer 
               FROM `call` 
               WHERE `C_ansornot`= 'answer' and idEmployee=$user and C_date= $date" ;
            $query2 = $this->db->select($sql1);
           // $answer=$this->$query2->result();


            $sql2 = "SELECT
               count(`C_ansornot`) notAnswer
               FROM `call` 
               WHERE `C_ansornot`= 'not answer' and idEmployee=$user and C_date= $date";

        $query3 = $this->db->select($sql2);
      //  $notanswer =  $this->$query3->result() ;

      $sql3="SELECT
               count(`C_ansornot`) Rejected 
               FROM `call` 
               WHERE `C_ansornot`= 'Rejected' idEmployee=$user and C_date= $date";  
               $query4=$this->db->select($sql3);
             //   $rejected = $query4->result() ;


       $sql4="SELECT
               count(`C_ansornot`) NotReachable 
               FROM `call` 
               WHERE `C_ansornot`= 'Not Reachable'idEmployee=$user and C_date= $date";
       $query5=$this->db->select($sql4);
                // $NotReachable= $query5->result() ;

        $sql5="SELECT
               count(`C_ansornot`) SwitchedOff
               FROM `call` 
               WHERE `C_ansornot`= 'Switched off' idEmployee=$user and C_date= $date";
                 $query6=$this->db->select($sql5);
                //  $switched = $query6->result() ;

        $sql6="SELECT
               count(`C_ansornot`) WrongNumber 
               FROM `call` 
               WHERE `C_ansornot`= 'Wrong Number/Invalid Number' idEmployee=$user and C_date= $date";
                $query7=$this->db->select($sql6);
                //  $WrongNumber = $query7->result() ;

         $return_array = array(
          //  'name'=>$row->E_name,
            'answer'=>$query2,
            'notAnswer'=>$query3,
            'NotReachable'=>$query4,
            'Rejected'=>$query5,
            'SwitchedOff'=>$query6,
            'WrongNumber'=>$query7

        );
        var_dump($query2);
         return  $return_array;

         }


}
```

the model file not pass data correctly...
 when i check i result like this...
[image]

the data display like this .

Comment: Which part of the code exactly is it you have a problem with? Is it `$answer=$this->$query2->result();` that isn't giving you the value you want?

Comment: There are easy ways to do this in codeigniter.. check this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

I find a lot of problems here but to answer your question the reason why you are seeing all that as a result is because you are not processing your query. You're just assigning those `SELECT` strings to the array.

However, the main problem is your code in general. Your code is not optimal and you are doing unnecessary queries. This is not only visually bad, but performance will be very slow with this structure. You should always try, if possible, to let MYSQL do the work for you. I would redo your SQL using `SUM` and `CASE` as such:

```
SELECT  
  u.E_name,
  sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'answer' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) answer,
  sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'not answer' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) notAnswer,
  sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Not Reachable' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) NotReachable,
  sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Rejected' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) Rejected,
  sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Switched Off' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) SwitchedOff,
  sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Wrong Number/Invalid Number' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) WrongNumber,
  count(*) total
FROM `calls` as cl 
JOIN `user` as u on u.idEmployee= cl.idEmployee
WHERE cl.idEmployee = $user_id
```

Then build your model method like this:

```
function daily_report() {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $date = $this->input->post('sdate');

    $select = "u.E_name,
               sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'answer' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) answer,
               sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'not answer' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) notAnswer,
               sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Not Reachable' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) NotReachable,
               sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Rejected' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) Rejected,
               sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Switched Off' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) SwitchedOff,
               sum(case when cl.C_ansornot = 'Wrong Number/Invalid Number' and cl.C_date='$date' then 1 else 0 end) WrongNumber,
               count(*) total";

    $this->db->select($select, false);
    $this->db->from("calls cl");
    $this->db->join("user u", "u.idEmployee= cl.idEmployee");
    $this->db->where("cl.idEmployee", $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```